# Apply only datepicker year fix from module material

Tags: angular, angular-material

The original problem was that in angular 2, in datepicker I cannot choose the year, I can only use the arrows left and right. After some digging, I ve discovered that this issue was fixed in Angular/material 6.0.0 (I had 2.0.0-beta.7).

Now the problem is that after upgrading the material module, all the modules crushed and gave me errors. So my question is how can I apply only the year datepicker part and not upgrading the modules?

Comment: The short answer is no. If there is no workaround at all, your only potential option is to create your own fork of 2.0.0-beta.7, apply the fix from v6, and build your own version of the library.

Comment: Not sure that I understand. If I apply the fix, why do I need to build my own version of the library?

Comment: By "apply the fix" I mean change the source code. That is the only way to fix it.